# git automation - setup local branch to receive commit from working branch, auto-add a file, commit with default message & push without checkouts

Tags: git, git-branch, branching-and-merging, git-push, git-cherry-pick

I have a fairly complex workflow. My working git branch is `master`. Assume that there exists a local branch called `push_branch`.

I'd like to automate the following steps whilst staying from within my working branch `master`.

- At a particular point in time, a commit to `master` is made with a user-specified commit message. This should trigger the following:

  1. An additional `side_effect_file` is generated.
  2. `push_branch` obtains the latest set of tracked files from `master`. It also receives the `side_effect_file` generated by the last commit made to `master` and adds to its staging index.
  3. A commit is made in `push_branch` (i.e. the `side_effect_file` is now committed in `push_branch`. (can use the same commit message as step 0 above or use a default commit_msg, it doesn't matter).
  4. `push_branch` pushes to github (or a suitable remote repo).

Here is a pictorial description of the desired workflow:
[image: complex_git_workflow]

In essence, all the working happens in `master`, which acts like a one-way feed to `push_branch`.  The real challenge is to automate the process seamlessly, whilst staying inside the working branch `master`  (or at-least appears seamlessly to the user by using a shell script which runs in the background).

What I don't want to do is to manually checkout `push_branch`, do a manual commit after adding `side_effect_file`, issue a commit message, do a manual push and then checkout `master` again. That is tedious, and not a sustainable solution.

Is this achievable? Maybe using `git-worktrees` (which I don't understand well)?

Comment: what is the side_effect_file. Will this file be merged to master at all?

Comment: It looks like you need git hooks https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks

Comment: Here is example with `post-receive` in use from githooks  https://gist.github.com/noelboss/3fe13927025b89757f8fb12e9066f2fa  maybe you can use some ideas from it.

Comment: The ```side_effect_file``` is an important file that gets generated post-commit containing the SHA of the commit and a few other information.